# How to create a realm instance (having nested objects) from a dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

For example, I have model `class` like this

```
class User: Objects {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var friends: List<User>?
```

}

and `Dictionary` like this

```
{
   firstName : "Mohshin"
   lastName : "Shah"
   friends : [
              {
               firstName : "Friend 1"
               lastName : "abc"
               },
              {
               firstName : "Friend 2"
               lastName : "def"
               }
              ]
}
```

I want to make a User object using the dictionary. I have tried Realm' `init(value: Any)` method and it is creating the User with flat values only but not the friends is initiated.

Comment: You have to add it yourself or use empty array

Comment: You mean to say I have to do it manually ?

Comment: and friends = [User]() like this ?

Comment: `var friends = List<User>()` would be best, the same for `firstName` and `lastName`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you're experiencing these issues is because the `List<User>` object must be initialized before use. Realm recommends declaring `List` and `RealmOptional` objects as `let` and therefore initializing them right inside the model.

In addition to that, you need to declare other properties using the `dynamic var` attribute in order for the properties to become accessors for the underlying database.

More on what I mentioned in the [Property Attributes](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-attributes) and [Supported Types](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#supported-types) sections of our documentation. With all that said, I recommend you change your model to the following:

```
import RealmSwift

class User: Object {
    dynamic var firstName: String?
    dynamic var lastName: String?
    let friends = List<User>()
}
```

I hope this helps and please let me know if you need anymore assistance.

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
func getRealm(dictionary:NSDictionary) {
    let first = dictionary.object(forKey: "first_name")
    let last = dictionary.object(forKey: "first_name")
    var friends = Array<Any>()
    for dict in dictionary.object(forKey: "friends") {
        var user = User()
        user.getRealm(dict)
        friends.append(user)
    }
}
```

Add a method like this in your realm model class

Comment: Actually I have created a generic protocol for mapping any instance. So better if a generic solution is there. I dont want to make class specific

Comment: Have you tried Mantle library? It will automatically place properties from array of dictionaries and return the list. It will be helpful if you could share what you have implemented so far, means the generic protocol you have implemented

Comment: No I'm not using `Mantle`.